# What video game is played in the movie “Drugstore June”?

Tags: game-identification

In the comedy film *[Drugstore June](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt19364132/reference/)* (2024), June’s (Esther Povitsky) brother, Jonathan (Brandon Wardell), is depicted engrossed in a first-person multiplayer team-based video game.

The player character is wielding a sci-fi/futuristic-looking gun. The game mode appears to be “capture the flag” or similar, with a Red team competing against a Blue Team, as evidenced by a message that reads “[…] captured the Blue Flag.”

The other players have colored indicators to show their team, location, and distance. The game also has a chat box and a kill feed on the screen.

Clip and screenshot of the game:

[image: clip of game]

[image: screenshot of game]

What video game was Jonathan playing in *Drugstore June*?

Comment: I've never played so I can't confirm, but it might be an entry in the *Tribes* series. *Tribes Ascend* was 12 years ago, and *Rivals* isn't out yet. A quick look on youtube doesn't really match but there could be graphics mods on Ascend or something.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe it's from the [***Midair 2***](https://midair2.gg/) Closed Beta Playtest, to which you can request access through [its Steam page](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1231210/Midair_2/).

[Here](https://youtu.be/SjHDBDHC0wc?feature=shared&t=225) is a video showing the gameplay, and a screenshot from said video:

[image: video screenshot]

Comment: Really interesting they went with a game thats in a closed beta in a TV show

Comment: @TimmyJim Mildly interesting that they went with a game that's in closed beta in a film.

Comment: Maybe it's a product placement?